# Can't format bootable USB stick [Ubuntu 19.04]

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, 19.04, format

I have created a bootable USB flash drive via Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator by following these instructions:
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

At 99% of the process it told me that the creation could not completed. No hint about what is going wrong. I used that USB stick for a bootable version of Ubuntu 18.04.

Now, I have an 8GB USB stick, without any device protection switch which I cannot format. The USB stick now keep formated as iso 9660.

I know that topic has been discussed a lot and in most cases it could solve by simple overriding the partitions with zeros. In my case nothing worked out what I tried.

For formatting back into FAT32 I tried following ways:

1. by dd: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdf bs=2048 count=32` (also with different byte size as well counts)
2. by mkusb (dus) => (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)
3. by: `sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdf`
4. gparted also couldn't do anything

Everything I do ends up in something like, `opening /dev/sdf': Read-only file system`

I'm wondering that also root couldn't format it.

Any ideas how I can format my usb flash drive to a FAT formatted flash drive?

Comment: Use "Disks" to unmount the ISO9660 partition , then use GParted to create a new partition table on the drive. There are also ways to restore the drive using mkusb.

Comment: When I try to unmount it via Disks it show following error message:
"Device '/dev/sdf1' is not mounted (udisks-error-quark, 7)".

Afterwards gparted cannot format the flash drive and show "read-only error" message.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! If the methods mentioned in your question aren’t working, I am afraid your USB flash drive is simply dying, I am sorry…

Comment: Hi Melebius, I think so too. Some of my friends told me the same... :(